# how to use Autocompleteextender in modal popupextender

Tags: css, asp.net

I am using autocompleteextender in a modalpopupextender....the dropdown in auto complete is shown in background....this problem occured in chrome....in firefox give expected output......

My code is....

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtpincode" runat="server" TabIndex="1"
    CssClass="autotxtbx" AutoPostBack="True" OnTextChanged="txtpincode_TextChanged"
    onchange="AutoClear()" Width="100"></asp:TextBox>

<cc1:AutoCompleteExtender ID="AutoCompleteExtender1"
    TargetControlID="txtpincode" ServiceMethod="getpincode"
    MinimumPrefixLength="1" OnClientItemSelected="ItemSelected"
    FirstRowSelected="true" runat="server" CompletionListItemCssClass="autocmpl"
    CompletionListHighlightedItemCssClass="autotxt" UseContextKey="True" />

<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnUserField" runat="server" />
```

I use this in a modal popup extender....the resul in chrome is....!

Comment: try giving `AutoCompleteType="Disabled"` and check

Comment: thanks bro...........the error is due to same updatepanel.....by adding different updatepanel to modelpopup ....i got correct result........

Comment: than u ....for ur ans......the error is due to same updatepanel.....by adding different updatepanel to modelpopup ....i got correct result.......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the only issue was with the `AutoCompleteType`. You can do it like this.

```
 `AutoCompleteType="Disabled"`
```

Comment: thanks bro...........the error is due to same updatepanel.....by adding different updatepanel to modelpopup ....i got correct result........